# How does the action queue work?

Tags: final-fantasy-tactics-a2

Every battle makes use of an *action queue* to determine the order in which units take their turns, and some units will have more turns to act than others. I know that the ordering and frequency of a units turns are determined by their **speed** stat, but the manual doesn't go into any details. I'd like to know exactly how speed factors into the queue ordering to make it easier for me to compare two units where one has a higher attack stat, and the other a higher speed stat.

How does speed factor into the ordering and frequency of unit turns in the action queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a theory that it is like the CT ([Charge Time](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Charge_Time)) system in FFTA.

This is evidenced by certain monster skills that have the effect "Damage + CT 0" (E.g. The Lamia's [Hand Slap](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_Tactics_A2:_Grimoire_of_the_Rift_Enemy_Abilities#Hand_Slap))

So like in FFTA, lets assume every unit has a hidden CT gauge that fills up to 100.

If we assume that each unit's CT fills by a number equal to their speed, plus a number based on their actions in the previous turn (Rough calculations from testing in Clan Trials yielded similar number to the ones in FFTA: +40 if you did nothing. +20 if you either moved but didn't perform an action, or vice versa. 0 if you did both).

When a unit's CT fills up, that unit is allowed to move or perform an action and their CT is reset at 0. However, have CT in excess of 100, due to their speed + action bonus (i.e., from Haste, not acting/moving), the remainder carries over. If there is more than one unit that fills up their CT gauge at the same time, it seems that the unit with the higher speed acts first (I'm not sure what happens with two units that share the same speed).

I assume that the turn order listed on the top screen is a reflection of the above conditions, while assuming that all units simply are not acting when it is their turn, and once a unit moves or performs an action, the turn order is recalculated.

Haste seems to fill your CT at twice the normal rate, while Slow fills your CT to half the normal rate. I've noticed that certain Guest/Monster units in certain missions may be given priority to their CT.

Comment: that does make sense

Comment: not sure exactly how much the remainder carries over, but I know its not possible for a hasted unit with speed > 100 to have unlimited moves.  There has to be a cap of some kind.  Either that or the CT gauge is more than 100.

Comment: Maybe the cap is ~200? This way it's possible for a sufficiently fast and hasted unit to move act again after one turn has passed.

Comment: I've found that it's possible to take 3 turns in a row, if you are sufficiently hasted, have high speed and don't act at all.